# Nombre de columna repetidos en diferentes tablas de sql server

Tags: sql-server

tengo una base de datos que no está relacionada, es decir no existen foreign keys, y necesito encontrar en qué tablas aparece el campo codigocliente, que es primary key de la tabla CLIENTE, sé que este campo por ejemplo lo encuntro en la tabla FACTURA y VENTASERVICIO de la base de datos, pero quisiera saber en qué otras tablas adicionalmente está. Por favor su apoyo...

Comment: Porcada campo primario debes buscar las columnas en otras tablas, intenta https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es útil, siempre que las columnas respeten el mismo nombre, cuando `codigocliente` en la tabla secundaria se llame `numerocliente`, obviamente esta solución no te serviría, de hecho es algo que no tampoco tiene solución.

```
SELECT  o.name
    FROM syscolumns c
    inner join sysobjects o
        on c.id = o.id
    where c.name = 'codigocliente'
    order by o.name
```

Esto, se ejecuta por base de datos, y te retornará, todas las tablas dónde exista una columna `codigocliente`. El código anterior es compatible con una gran variedad de versiones de sql server, aunque para ser estrictos, en versiones de 2008 o superiores, se recomienda:

```
SELECT  o.name
    FROM sys.columns c
    inner join sys.objects o
        on c.object_id = o.object_id
    where c.name = 'codigocliente'
    order by o.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar la respuesta de Patricio, dejo una alternativa que involucra vistas del sistema compatibles con el estándar ANSI (y con ello otros sistemas de base de datos).

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='codigocliente'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```